# In Xcode's Interface Builder, how to autosize/space controls relative to each other and NOT the superview

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

It seems that the only way you can specify AutoSizing/Spacing is relative to the superview. Is there a way i can specify relative AutoSizing/Spacing to another view ? Say i want two views inside the superview to always have the a spacing of 6 pixels when the superview is resized. Is there any way to do this in IB or will i have to resort to coding it in manually ?

Answer (score 2):

In IB, click on the file inspector (The first icon), then make sure auto layout is not checked.  Then go to the size inspector (The 5th icon) and make your changes.

**Edit:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [fredandrandall.com](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/saveasautolayout.png))</sub>

Comment: I dont see a auto layout option in the file inspector. (This is Xcode 4.4.1) But i still dont see how that would help with what i want, in the sizing tab there is no option to specify sizing relative to views. Can you please explain more ?

Comment: Okay My Bad, should have said i am working in iOS. This seems to be valid only for Mac. Is that correct ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I assumed that iOS functioned the same way as Cocoa.